# How to make a post request to API Rest in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a piece of code that sends me, via a post request, a json to my API Rest; and works!

**main.cpp**

```
void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "reply delete!";
    qDebug() << "https post_request done!";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QUrl url("https://.../");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

    QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, replyFinished);

    quint8 speed = 0x12;
    quint8 accelleration = 0x2b;

    QString json = QString("{\"speed\":\"%1\",\"acceleration\":\"%2\"}").arg(speed).arg(accelleration);

    manager->post(request, json.toUtf8());

    return a.exec();
}
```

But when I want to integrate this piece of code in my program, it does not work. Briefly, my program gets through the SIGNAL and SLOT mechanism, a QByteArray, from which I take the data and I send them to my API Rest.

This is my **Header.h**

```
...
class Packet : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Packet();

public slots:
    void receivePayload(QByteArray &bufferToJson);
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager;
    quint8 m_speed;
    quint8 m_accelleration;

public:
    QString json;
};
...
```

This is my **class.cpp**

```
Packet::Packet()
    : m_manager { new QNetworkAccessManager }
{
    QObject::connect(m_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void Packet::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "reply delete!";
    qDebug() << "https post_request done!";
}

void Packet::receivePayload(QByteArray &bufferToJson){
    m_speed = bufferToJson.at(0);
    m_accelleration = bufferToJson.at(1);

    QUrl url("https://.../");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    QString json = QString("{\"speed\":\"%1\",\"acceleration\":\"%2\"}").arg(m_speed).arg(m_accelleration);
    m_manager->post(request, json.toUtf8());
}
```

What's the problem of my change?

Comment: The only difference I see is the different connect syntax: connect(m_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Packet::replyFinished); Your program, does it also start QCoreApplication.exec?

Comment: @Rvdk I changed the connect because kept giving me error. I added in the main a.exec (), but without any benefit. I also created a QNetworkReply instance to print an error, `qDebug() << reply->error();` but it tells me **NoError**